# Change browser tab status

Tags: php, html, css, browser

I have an upload form that posts a file. When I click submit, the browser tab status naturally changes to a loading/waiting image to show the page is doing something while the upload takes place.

My issue is that when the file is done uploading and is posted to the upload page I have set, the browser status stays as loading at that point as well. At this point I can change the page and the script that the file is posted to will finish. To show the user that the uploading process is done, I was wondering if there was a way to reset the browser tab status so it does not show as loading as this point.

```
<form action="testing12345.php" target="progressFrame" method="post" id="uploadform" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="beginUpload();">
<input type="hidden" name="UPLOAD_IDENTIFIER" id="progress_key" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $session->username; ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="processing" />
<input type="file" name="Filedata" id="Filedata" />
</form>
```

Comment: It should automatically return to idle status

Comment: firefox 4.01 in ubuntu. It stays as loading until the upload script the file is posted to is complete. That script will complete however even if the page is changed when the upload is finished.

Comment: useless feature, 99% of users wont look for custom set messages within the browser, you should code your application to display status messages within the users eye level & inside your page.

Comment: I suppose, but it would be nice. I just know that myself I always pay attention to those things. Maybe it is because I am more observant. I thought maybe there was something quick I could do with html or css to stop it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using JavaScript? Use `window.stop();`. Though I do find it strange that the browser isn't stopping itself.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no you can't toy with the tab *activity indicator*.

*Your question seems to tell "The activity indicator keeps cycling even after the upload is done".*

The reason it keeps cycling is because it's doing background processing. If the processing seems done but it keeps cycling, it might be an issue with your firefox configuration, the network or the "return script" (waiting for an answer).

It also seems you are submitting your form to a frame (`target="progressFrame"`). If this frame keeps trying to load (after uploading the file) it will keep the activity indicator active.

*But you said it stopped cycling after uploading in the comments...*

If it does stop once the file finish uploading, then there is no problem and it should stay that way. Even if the user can keep on browsing the site, if they close the browser, the upload will be interrupted. This is the only indicator they seems to have, so it should stay. You should tell your users when the uploading is done by some way.